# Multiple calls to a Alamofire request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have used Alamofire for uploading images in multipart form data. I am successful in achieving my target. Each time I upload an image, I call the "uploadDocWebService" function. So the number of times the function is called, is equal to the number of images. I am hopeless in identifying the result of each call. My images are uploaded successfully. In case there is a server failure, or internet connection failure the uploading fails, I cannot identify which image I should delete from the view, that has failed. I pass indexPath as a parameter for each image upload. But that indexPath updates to the latest image upload before I receive the result for the first image upload. Can any one suggest me a better approach for this situation.

Here is the code I use for image upload:

```
func uploadDocWebservice(fileUrl: NSURL , progressView : PWProgressView , index : String , imageData : NSData? , name : String , mimeType : String , uploadType : String){

let url = "\(kBaseURL)\(uploadDocsUrl)"

var type = String()
var networkGroupId = String(SingletonClass.sharedInstance.selectedNetworkId!)

if SingletonClass.sharedInstance.groupPopUp == true {

    type = "group"
    networkGroupId = String(SingletonClass.sharedInstance.selectedSubNetworkOrGroup!)

}else {

    type = "network"
}

Alamofire.upload(
    .POST,
    url,
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        if uploadType == "Image" {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart( data: imageData! , name: "file", fileName: name, mimeType: mimeType)
        }else {
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: fileUrl, name: "file")
        }
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"\(SingletonClass.sharedInstance.tokenId)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"token")
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"\(type)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"networkGroup")
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"\(networkGroupId)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"networkGroupId")

    },
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in

                let ratio: Float = Float(totalBytesRead) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToRead)
                // Call main thread.
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    progressView.progress = ratio
                })

            }

            upload.responseJSON { response in

                let dataString = NSString(data: response.data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print(dataString)

                self.edited = true

                do{

                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response.data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary

                    if let success = json!["success"] as? Int {

                        if success == 1 {

                            let id = json!["response"]!.objectForKey("id") as! String
                            let docName = "\(json!["response"]!.objectForKey("name") as! String).\(json!["response"]!.objectForKey("ext") as! String)"
                            let dic = ["name" : docName , "Id" : id]
                            self.uploadedDocsIdArray.addObject(dic)
                            self.uploadedArrayJustNames.addObject(docName)
                            print(self.uploadedDocsIdArray)

                        }else {

                            // delete image from view here

                        }

                    }

                }catch{

                    // delete image from view here
                    invokeAlertMethod("Error", msgBody: "Invalid Json", delegate: self)

                }

            }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):

            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)

}
```